# Altering Value of Multiple Cells Using a Button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to start by letting you know I'm a mechanical engineer with minimal experience coding. I recently have tried to make a simple spreadsheet to help me track inventory of the items in my work area. I make the same thing just with different sized components. I would like to make a spreadsheet that allows me to click different buttons (assigned a size) that allow me to take away inventory regarding the specific size components. What I have now is a script assigned to an image that does exactly what I want but I don't think it's the most efficient way of doing it.

I found some script example that defines a cell range as a variable and subtracts one and basically copied it a few times. I tried 
`var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B8, B10, B12:B14");` 
but I kept getting an error saying the range not found. If there's a way to compress what I have I would greatly appreciate it.

````
   // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B8");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);  // this increments by -1 but could be any number

  // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B10");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);  // this increments by -1 but could be any number

  // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B12:B14");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);  // this increments by -1 but could be any number

  // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B16:B17");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);  // this increments by -1 but could be any number

  // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B19");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue - 1);  // this increments by -1 but could be any number
} ```
````

Comment: Change getvalue to getvalues

Comment: Then iterate the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Work with [range lists](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) instead of ranges and implement a loop

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(["B2:B8", "B10", "B12:B14"]);
  for(var i=0; i<rangeList.getRanges().length; i++){
    var range = rangeList.getRanges()[i];
    var rangeValues = range.getValues();
    for(var j=0; j<rangeValues.length; j++){
      rangeValues[j][0]=rangeValues[j][0]-1;
    }
    range.setValues(rangeValues);
  }
}
```

> Mind: Since some of your ranges contain several cells, you need to
>   implement a second loop, to change the values you need to loop through
>   every element of the range array and change its value, before
>   assigning the array of values back to the sheets range.

There is also a [third party library](https://github.com/tanaikech/RangeListApp) that allows you to work with range lists in an easier way.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the RangeList library. What you provided worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and if you can change them by adding the correct number of parameters one for each range.  I added a sheet clear to the function for you to play with them. Try running myfun() and then run funtest() and you'll see what I mean.

```
function myfun() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();//remove this for the real function
  var rgA=["B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B10","B12","B13","B14","B16","B17","B19"];
  var inA=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
  if(arguments.length==inA.length) {inA=arguments;}
  rgA.forEach(function(r,i){sh.getRange(rgA[i]).setValue(sh.getRange(rgA[i]).getValue()+inA[i]);});  
} 

function funtest() {
  myfun(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4);
}
```

[Javascript 1.6 arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)